# Missing delimiter (. inserted) .<to be read again>- : Can't write curly brackets

Tags: brackets, braces, delimiters

I'm trying for so long now to write this

```
$ \displaystyle{ x = \Big{ -\frac{b}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{27} + \frac{b^2}{4}} \Big}^{\frac{1}{3}} + \{-\frac{b}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{27} + \frac{b^2}{4}} \}^{ \frac{1}{3}} } $
```

The problem is it won't accept me adding those curly brackets in any form, be it

```
\{ \}
\left{ \right}
\Big{  \Big}
```

etc. Without adding curly braces visible in the output, it works fine

These are all my packages

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath} % allows piecewise functions
\usepackage{amsfonts} % allows using additional font commands
\usepackage{amssymb} % for varpropto - proportion symbol
\usepackage{graphicx} % include graphics / image package
\usepackage{fullpage} % page formatting
\usepackage{tabto}    % required by \tab command (sometimes glitches, use \quad, or \qquad instead)
\usepackage{mathtools} % needed for under / over braces
\usepackage{textcomp} % needed for \sim (tilde) and \texttildelow 
\usepackage{amssymb} % for (small)setminus
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % for caligraphic letters
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for underlining \uline{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % OT1 (Old Text encoding) = not a good idea to have
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

I cannot get past this sentence after almost 1 hour of troubleshooting! What's wrong? I'm using TexMaker. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\displaystyle` does not take an argument so  `\displaystyle{...}` should be `\displaystyle ...` otherwise the spurious `{}` prevent white space stretching and prevents line breaking, but why use `$\displaymath...$` rather than real display math `\[...\]` ?

Comment: Apparently `\displaystyle` works both ways. That wasn't the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: No it does not work both ways. the `{}` in the above are unrelated to `\displaystyle` and destroy the inline white space behaviour as I said. It doesn't address your question which is why I left as a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no

```
\left{ \right}
\Big{  \Big}
```

They should be

```
\left\{ \right\}
\Bigl\{  \Bigr\}
```

Please observe `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`, not simply `\Big`, which gives different spacing.